# 50,000 file in one directory, what is my best option?

Tags: web-server, performance, directory, filesystems, nosql

I'm forced to have this directory structure
/var/www/$WEBSITE/$DIR1/$DIR2/$FILES

for each of those $FILES, there is approx 50,000 XHTML pages.

I'm running Cherokee, which has new front-end caching support.
But i'm somewhat memory limited, so I can't cache the whole thing.
I believe I can cache just the listing, which is the worst part.

What can I do on the file system side of things? 
I normally use ext4 (my server is using ext3), But i know ReiserFS is preferred for this type of situation.  I could possibly just mount that $WEBSITE in ReiserFS.  I really am not looking forward to repartitioning things, and would love to work around this.

Can i do a staggered subdirectories somewhere on the filesystem and just symlink them all to $DIR2?  Would that help make this nasty situation perform better, with less pain from the ext3?

i really don't want anything RDB, I would consider a NOSQL option If I could somehow create a faux filesystem from it.  that would be such a cool option, just not sure it even exists. Possibly something FUSE related exists?

the whole site already exists, and it basically is just a fancy directory listing.  The files get written once, and then just read from there on out.  There is no chance the number of files per directory would increase from this point.

Comment: I just enabled dir_index, this could help the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem

My FS performance was making me uncomfortable at a mere ~5000 files, which is why I posted this question.  I normally would use Ext4, and have used XFS; which has always been a solid-performer; but i already had everything installed on Ext3.

Ext4 has Htree indexes enabled by default, which would make this a non-issue.
Ext3 has support for Htree indexes, dir_index; however, it was not enabled on my FS.

```
# I Checked Ext features, no dir_index
$ tune2fs -l /dev/xvda | grep features

# Enabled dir_index
$ tune2fs -O dir_index /dev/xvda
```

I did have to fsck after I rebooted, but otherwise it enabled successfully.
When I listed files in those directories, the performance issues were gone.
I could avoid implementing a NoSQL based VFS, gridfs-fuse; and I could avoid a resize/repartition on my fully allocated HD.

As for changing my FS, I wanted to avoid that kind of disk operation if at all possible.

Comment: Mentioning that it was on Xen would have been helpful.  You might try setting the disk elevator queue to noop.  Add elevator=noop to your kernel parameters.

Answer (score 2):

50,000 files should not be enough to cause a significant speed issue on Linux. You mention caching the listing, so I'm thinking you are doing some kinda of processing on the files instead of plain serving.  I would look for issues on how you process the files.

Comment: I just checked my server, it's using ext3. 
and in my unfortunate case, does not have dir_index enabled.  Which would put performance issue well below 50,000.  I don't fault your answer for this, as i failed to explain this.

Also, the way you stated "Linux" is incorrect.  i have no doubt the kernel could handle that many files, it is the filesystem that might not be up to the task.

However, I don't process the files from that folder.  They are static XHTML files.  The only dynamic page as the directory listing, which I will set to cache.

Comment: I still think you have some other issue.  I created 50,000 1k files in ext3 loopback filesystem and "ls >> /dev/null" takes .2seconds.

Comment: yes the additional major issue is that this is a xen VM.  I rent this baby from a hosting company, it is my personal VPS (Not work related, which is why it is a rented VM).  BTW, when you tested it did you make sure dir_index was not enabled?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend XFS with one possible exception: if you often need to remove lots of files from that directory tree, delete performance is not stellar in XFS. This has been improved a bit with the new *delaylog* mount parameter, though.

Other than that XFS won't even cough with 50 000 files in a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try XFS. I have large directories running on the XFS filesystem with good results. `ls`, `du` and other file operations are noticeably better than on ext3. Either way, for scalability, it may make sense to develop a cleaner directory structure.

```
[root@bootylicious /data/print]# ls -1 | wc -l
431801
```

Comment: Site won't need to scale upwards from this point.  nothing is even written on any normal usage.